# problem with codeigniter using odbc database driver

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter, odbc

i’ve run into a curious problem with codeigniter's odbc driver.
i’m connecting from a linux machine to an MSSQL 2008 machine using FreeTDS.

while i get that the ‘num_rows’ function always returns -1, and that is fully a database/driver issue - for some reason when i try to create a ->result(), the whole application crashes (error 500, sometimes just a blank page), if i’m lucky, i get an error message informing me that the application died because it tried to allocated 2 terrabytes of memory(!).

This happens irregularly, ie: every few refreshes. sometimes it runs fine, sometimes the page returns error 500 and sometimes it gives the memory allocation error - in any case it’s not really something that can be reproduced with percision, and the queries are SUPER simple.

ideas anyone?

Comment: not nearly enough specific info. for people to help you...

Comment: what information should i provide? i can respond with specifics if you can direct me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ha ha, this happend to me too!  And [I've complained](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/126971/) to the devs about it, and they [ignored me](http://codeigniter.com/bug_tracker/bug/7389/).

When you call result(), it will loop through every single possible result, and store the record into a massive internal array.  See `system/database/DB_result.php` while loop at the end of result_object() and result_array()

There are three ways of fixing it.

### The easy way:

`LIMIT` (or [`TOP` in MSSQL](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx)) your results in the SQL query.

```
SELECT TOP(100) * FROM Table
```

### The UPDATED unbuffered way:

Use the `unbuffered_row()` function that was [introduced](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/pull/1372) 2 years after this question was asked.

```
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
// not $query->result() because that loads everything into an internal array.
// and not $query->first_row() because it does the same thing (as of 2013-04-02)
while ($record = $query->unbuffered_row('array')) { 
    // code...
}
```

### The hard way:

Use a *proper* result object that uses PHP5 iterators (that the devs don't like because it excludes php4).  Slap something like this in your DB_result.php file:

```
-class CI_DB_result {
+class CI_DB_result implements Iterator {

    var $conn_id        = NULL;
    var $result_id      = NULL;
    var $result_array   = array();
    var $result_object  = array();
-   var $current_row    = 0;
+   var $current_row    = -1;
    var $num_rows       = 0;
    var $row_data       = NULL;
+   var $valid          = FALSE;


    /**
    function _fetch_assoc() { return array(); } 
    function _fetch_object() { return array(); }

+   /**
+    * Iterator implemented functions
+    * http://us2.php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php
+    */
+   
+   /**
+    * Rewind the database back to the first record
+    *
+    */
+   function rewind()
+   {
+       if ($this->result_id !== FALSE AND $this->num_rows() != 0) {
+           $this->_data_seek(0);
+           $this->valid = TRUE;
+           $this->current_row = -1;
+       }
+   }
+   
+   /**
+    * Return the current row record.
+    *
+    */
+   function current()
+   {
+       if ($this->current_row == -1) {
+           $this->next();
+       }
+       return $this->row_data;
+   }
+   
+   /**
+    * The current row number from the result
+    *
+    */
+   function key()
+   {
+       return $this->current_row;
+   }
+   
+   /**
+    * Go to the next result.
+    *
+    */
+   function next()
+   {
+       $this->row_data = $this->_fetch_object();
+       if ($this->row_data) {
+           $this->current_row++;
+           if (!$this->valid)
+               $this->valid = TRUE;
+           return TRUE;
+       } else {
+           $this->valid = FALSE;
+           return FALSE;
+       }
+   }
+   
+   /**
+    * Is the current_row really a record?
+    *
+    */
+   function valid()
+   {
+       return $this->valid;
+   }
+   
 }
 // END DB_result class
```

Then to use it, instead of calling `$query->result()` you use just the object without the `->result()` on the end like `$query`.  And all the internal CI stuff still works with `result()`.

```
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
foreach ($query as $record) { // not $query->result() because that loads everything into an internal array.
    // code...
}
```

By the way, my Iterator code working with their code has some logic problems with the whole -1 thing, so don't use both `$query->result()` and `$query` on the same object.  If someone wants to fix that, you are awesome.

Comment: correction, this *was not* the problem with my setup, but as i rewrote the driver completely, i found your code profoundly helpful, and my result object is now pure php5, very nice.

Comment: Bummer :(  What was the issue?

Comment: issue was bad driver configuration, freetds, if you know it

Comment: Looks like someone added unbuffered_row() about a year ago to limit the memory usage: https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/pull/1372